# How to get the same default Radio button in IE11 as it is in IE8?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, web-applications

The default radio button is displayed as blue colour in IE8 but it is black in IE11. I want to display the default IE8 radio button in IE11 also. Is it possible to do this. What changes i need to do?

Comment: You could have the browser emulate ie8 for that specific page but the entire page will be run as if it were in ie8...

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

Comment: @brso05: i want it in native mode..is it possible to do so ?

Comment: what do you mean by "native mode"?

Comment: @brso05 : i mean without adding the "X-UA-Compatible" tag..

Comment: I think that styling for radio buttons is pretty restrictive you can look and see if there is anything you can do with css or javascript to change the look...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`-ms-check`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pseudo-element to style radio buttons and checkboxes in IE.

```
input::-ms-check {
    color: blue;
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnh1f4t6/).

Comment: It is working but the look and feel is different...i want it to be same as the one in default IE8 radio button.